# wp-content empty - site still working

Tags: wordpress

A friend of mine asked me to install a plugin for him on a site he runs.

A very strange thing occured, I can not install any plugin or theme because everything in the wp-content folder is missing, but the site is still running.

Anyone knows what might be going on?

Comment: Any more information that can be provided?  Link to site?

Comment: The site is fibromyalgie.ch

Comment: Also, I'm using the wp-andreas theme, WordPress version is 2.8.3

Comment: Are you sure everything is missing? I can access http://www.fibromyalgie.ch/wp-content/themes/wp-andreas01-12/img/front.jpg, http://www.fibromyalgie.ch/wp-content/themes/wp-andreas01-12/index.php.

Comment: That's the weird part, going through FTP or the web host's file manager, I can't open wp-content. I receive messages saying that it's empty.